# Comparing node values and writing the value of another node based on that comparison with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I apologize if this seems obtuse or oversimplified. I'm certainly no expert with XSLT.

I have two XMLs:

**XML #1**

```
<simpletable>

   <strow>
     <stentry props="part-name">This is a test</stentry>
     <stentry props="part-number">1008590-00-C</stentry>
   </strow>
   <strow>
     <stentry props="part-name">Another test</stentry>
     <stentry props="part-number">1008590-00-D</stentry>
   </strow>
   <strow>
     <stentry props="part-name">Still another test</stentry>
     <stentry props="part-number">1030348-00-A</stentry>
   </strow>

</simpletable>
```

**XML #2**

```
<simpletable relcolwidth="5* 40* 15* 5* 35*">
           <sthead translate="yes">
              <stentry>No.</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Description</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Number</stentry>
              <stentry>Qty</stentry>
              <stentry>Comments</stentry>
           </sthead>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">P​L​A​S​T​I​C​S​ ​S​U​B​ ​A​S​Y​ ​-​ ​F​R​O​N​T​ ​F​A​S​C​I​A​ </stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1008590-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">P​L​A​S​T​I​C​S​ ​S​U​B​ ​A​S​Y​ ​-​ ​F​R​O​N​T​ ​F​A​S​C​I​A​ ​W​/​ ​P​A​R​K​ ​A​S​S​I​S​T​ </stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1030348-00-A</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="comment">With holes for park assist sensors</stentry>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">2</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">B​r​a​c​k​e​t​ ​F​e​n​d​e​r​ ​F​R​T​ ​F​a​s​c​i​a​ ​L​e​f​t</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">6005888-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           ...
</simpletable>
```

I'm trying to write an XSLT that compares the part numbers between the two XMLs. If they are equal, then write the part name from XML #1 to XML #2. So, the result would be:

```
<simpletable relcolwidth="5* 40* 15* 5* 35*">
           <sthead translate="yes">
              <stentry>No.</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Description</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Number</stentry>
              <stentry>Qty</stentry>
              <stentry>Comments</stentry>
           </sthead>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">​Another test</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1008590-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">Still another test</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1030348-00-A</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="comment">With holes for park assist sensors</stentry>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">2</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-name">B​r​a​c​k​e​t​ ​F​e​n​d​e​r​ ​F​R​T​ ​F​a​s​c​i​a​ ​L​e​f​t</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">6005888-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           ...
</simpletable>
```

The transform I have written so far is just not right and apparently oversimplified. The templates are not iterating the way that I would expect.

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" doctype-system="reference.dtd" doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Reference//EN"/>

<xsl:param name="removeAttributesNamed" select="'|domains|ditaarch:DITAArchVersion|class|'"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputDoc" select="document('output-test.xml')/descendant::stentry[@props='part-number']"/>
<xsl:variable name="outputDoc" select="document('BODY.xml')/descendant::stentry[@props='part-number']"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ref">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>            
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test=
        "not(contains($removeAttributesNamed,
        concat('|', name(), '|')
        )
        )
        ">
        <xsl:call-template name="ref"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="combine">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$inputDoc = $outputDoc">
            <stentry translate="yes" props="part-name">                
                <xsl:for-each  select="document('output-test.xml')/descendant::stentry[@props='part-name']">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:for-each>                
            </stentry>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stentry[@props='part-name']">
    <xsl:call-template name="combine"/>
</xsl:template>
```

With this XSLT, my result is instead:

```
<simpletable relcolwidth="5* 40* 15* 5* 35*">
           <sthead translate="yes">
              <stentry>No.</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Description</stentry>
              <stentry>Part Number</stentry>
              <stentry>Qty</stentry>
              <stentry>Comments</stentry>
           </sthead>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="part-name">This is a testAnother testStill another test</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1008590-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="part-name">This is a testAnother testStill another test</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">1030348-00-A</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="comment">With holes for park assist sensors</stentry>
           </strow>
           <strow>
              <stentry translate="no" props="annotation">2</stentry>
              <stentry translate="yes" props="part-name">This is a testAnother testStill another test</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="part-number">6005888-00-D</stentry>
              <stentry translate="no" props="quantity">1</stentry>
              <stentry/>
           </strow>
           ...
</simpletable>
```

One of the problems that I see is it looks like I'm comparing node sequences as opposed to the actual string values of each part number. But I feel like I'm a bit in over my head right now and not sure how I would do that. So, I'm looking for some guidance that will help me refine my oh so rough solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The transform I have written so far is just not right and apparently
>   oversimplified.

IMHO, you are over-complicating this, not over-simplifying.

Assuming you are processing the document you marked as **XML #2**, and supposing that the other document, marked by you as **XML #1**, is named "otherfile.xml", the following dstylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="part" match="strow" use="stentry[@props='part-number']" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stentry[@props='part-name']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="matching-part" select="key('part', ../stentry[@props='part-number'], document('otherfile.xml'))" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$matching-part">
                <xsl:value-of select="$matching-part/stentry[@props='part-name']"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should return the requested result. Note the use of **key** to lookup the values from the other file.

Comment: Thanks much! It's not the first time that I have been accused of over-complicating things, particularly when it comes to XSLT. I had actually seen keys used in a couple examples that sorta looked like it was close to solving the same kind of problem but wasn't sure how I would use them in my case. I guess I should have paid closer attention to how they were used and then reviewed the spec more thoroughly.